# I am trying to do the function add one month to the current month in JSP and show the result in textbook in html

Tags: html, jsp, intellij-idea

This is my input box that should show date in one month.

```
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datum_uplate">Datum isteka:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datum_isteka" name="datum_isteka" >
```

This is my jsp code, I don't want to use javascript for security reasons.

```
    <%

      LocalDateTime.now().plusMonths(1);
      int months = int.Parse("datum_isteka".toString());
      LocalDateTime newDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusMonths(months);
    %>
```

And when I launch my tomcat this is what comes up:

```
 Type Exception Report

 Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

 Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:60)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: Can you see any other errors in console or log file while deploying your application in tomcat ?

Comment: The only other that I can see is in jsp code with the Parse class

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of the below line:

```
int months = int.Parse("datum_isteka".toString());
```

The syntax that you are using will not work in `Java`.

If I am thinking correct, you are trying to get the input value and want evaluate in the `jsp`, which not possible because jsp code will executed way before you can see the html content in browser.

If you don't want use `JavaScript` in your code then to get the `textbox` value you need to submit the page like below:

```
<!-- here I am using post method, coz I dont want users to see the content in the browser -->
<form method="post" action="index.jsp">

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="datum_uplate">Datum isteka:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datum_isteka" name="datum_isteka" >        

  <input type="submit" value="Get Months">
</form>

 <%
  // to get the you use the java code
  if (request.getParameter("datum_isteka") != null ) {
     LocalDateTime.now().plusMonths(1);
     //int months = int.Parse("datum_isteka".toString());
     int months = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("datum_isteka")); // here you may need to handle empty string, `parseInt` method will throw error if the given value is empty, i.e; `datum_isteka` textbox value.
     LocalDateTime newDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusMonths(months);
  }
%>
```

Now the `newDate` will have the required value.

Comment: So what type of data I should put into the database so it can be inserted ?
    INSERT INTO uplate (iznos, datum_uplate,datum_isteka,id_clan,tip_clan_id,id_naloga ) VALUES ( '24','2018-05-07','' , 5, 2,(SELECT id_naloga from clanovi where id_clan=5 ));
: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'datum_isteka' at row 1
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:601)

Comment: And it doesn't matter if the user can see the result..it can also be javascript, I only want to get it work automatically